# How deluge is packaged for windows?

Tags: python, configuration, deluge

I recently discovered that deluge- a Torrent client software https://deluge-torrent.org/ is built using python and it is available for windows, linux and Mac. But as per my knowledge unlike c and java programs, python programs can't be turned into executables, so how does they provide .exe installer for windows?

Note- I know libraries like pyinstaller can do this but I doubt that it works for such a big application like deluge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [Bbfreeze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze) & [NSIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/) as detailed in their [Github repo](https://github.com/deluge-torrent/deluge/blob/develop/packaging/win32/Win32%20README.txt):

```
== Dependencies ==
 * Deluge build: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Installing/Source#WindowsDependencies
 * Bbfreeze: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze
 * NSIS: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download
```